# POSTGRESQL: ERROR: column "" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables in a Postgresql database. It is a helpdesk database and they are `job_ticket`'s and `tech`'s. I am looking to get the average first response for each tech.
 My query looks like below.

```
SELECT 
  concat(tech.first_name, ' ', tech.last_name) AS Tech,
  AVG((ticket.first_response_date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney') - (ticket.report_date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney')) AS First_Reply_Time
FROM 
  public.job_ticket ticket
  INNER JOIN public.tech tech
  ON ticket.client_id = tech.client_id;
```

But I keep getting the error `ERROR:  column "tech.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

What is the best way to pull out the Tech and their avg first response time?

Comment: You have `AVG()` but no `GROUP BY`.  What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: Please provide sample data for what you want.

Comment: I get that @GordonLinoff but putting the statements in `GROUP BY` still gave errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the group by to the end of your query should be fine :

```
SELECT 
  concat(tech.first_name, ' ', tech.last_name) AS Tech,
  AVG((ticket.first_response_date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney') - (ticket.report_date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney')) AS First_Reply_Time
FROM 
  public.job_ticket ticket
  INNER JOIN public.tech tech
  ON ticket.client_id = tech.client_id
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Ekiz that worked perfectly.
Out of interest what does that do?

Comment: I recommend reading about GROUP BY statements and aggregate functions:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp